# Pygame graphics error: Couldn't open blue.png

Tags: python, graphics, pygame

I've been learning graphics in Pygame, and I tried to blit the background, but when I ran my program, it gave me this error:

```
pygame.error: Couldn't open blue.png
the png and the python file are in the same folder on my desktop.
```

My code is shown below:

```py
from os import path

background = pygame.image.load('blue.png')
background_rect = background.get_rect()

screen.blit(background, background_rect)
screen.blit(background, background_rect)
all_sprites.draw(screen)
pygame.display.flip()
screen.fill(BLACK)
```

Comment: That should work - can you double check the paths, filenames and file permissions? Or try an absolute path to the image?

Comment: Thanks, i double checked the path and i forgot about the folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this doesn't work because `'blue.png'` is simply a string; you must use `path.join("NAME OF BASE DIRECTORY", "blue.png")`. this will tell pygame where to look for a file with a name `"blue.png"`. there are a few ways that you can make this run faster: call `pygame.image.load(path.join("BASE DIR", "blue.png")).convert()` this puts the image in the same format as the window making rendering much faster, you are blitting to the screen twice which is pointless and slows time, and if you aren't using OpenGL just use `pygame.update()` as it is slightly faster.